# How do I remove a specific line and lines just before and after it?

Tags: command-line

I'm making a summary of the `history.log` files in `/var/log/apt`. To that end, I want to remove lines containing a certain pattern as well as the line immediately preceding and the line immediately following the line containing the pattern.

In the following example:

```
 1  Start-Date: 2012-10-18  17:34:12
 2  Commandline: /usr/sbin/synaptic
 3  Install: qpdf:i386 (3.0.2-1)
 4  End-Date: 2012-10-18  17:34:21

 5  Start-Date: 2012-10-20  16:56:26
 6  Commandline: apt-get upgrade
 7  End-Date: 2012-10-20  16:56:39

 8  Start-Date: 2012-10-24  09:15:11
 9  Commandline: apt-get upgrade
10  End-Date: 2012-10-24  09:15:26

11  Start-Date: 2012-10-26  18:40:20
12  Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-install-packages' sender=':1.196'
13  Install: gcolor2:i386 (0.4-2.1ubuntu1)
14  End-Date: 2012-10-26  18:40:31

15  Start-Date: 2012-10-27  07:20:03
16  Commandline: apt-get upgrade
17  End-Date: 2012-10-27  07:20:11

18  Start-Date: 2012-10-29  16:32:33
19  Commandline: /usr/sbin/synaptic
20  Install: policykit-desktop-privileges:i386 (0.12)
21  End-Date: 2012-10-29  16:32:40
```

I want to remove lines 5, 6, and 7, lines 8, 9, and 10 and lines 15, 16, and 17.

All I can manage is `sed -rs ''/apt-get\ upgrade/,+1'd;'` which removes the line containing `apt-get upgrade` and the line following it.

Comment: So you want to remove all lines before and after each apt-get upgrade.

Comment: No, just the one line above and the one line below.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, something ugly, but working:

```
pattern="apt-get\ upgrade"
prog="BEGIN {b=0} /$pattern/ {print; b=1; next} {if (b==1) {b=0;next;} else {print;}}"
cat test | awk "$prog" | tac | awk "$prog" |tac | grep -v "$pattern"
```

Second line create a awk program that remove the line following the one where the pattern is found.

Then this program is run on the test file, the output is reversed, the program run again, output is reversed, and line with pattern are removed.

Something shorter, with the same approach:

```
cat test | sed -e "/$pattern/{n;d}" | tac | sed -e "/$pattern/,+1d" |tac
```

I believe that reversing the file is mandatory, because to my knowledge, stream-processing tools cant go *backward*.

Comment: I like the cat/tac trick. I think that's going to work :)

Comment: Can you explain the role of `$` in `/$pattern/`? **1**: It works but doesn't seem essential because `/apt-get\ upgrade/` works as well. **2** When I use `/$^Upgrade/`, the `$` seems to prevent anything from happening. Just `^Upgrade` works.

Comment: It's just to avoid repeating the same string several time... note the double cotes, which don't block shell interpretation (unlike simple cote) : so $pattern is substituted *by the shell* with "upgrade".

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how general you want it, but an `awk` that does this specific task could be:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ RS=""; ORS="\n\n"; } !/apt-get upgrade/' /var/log/apt/history.log
```

you can extend it with more patterns

```
awk 'BEGIN{ RS=""; ORS="\n\n"; } !/apt-get upgrade/ && !/apt-get install hello/' /var/log/apt/history.log
```

It works by setting the record separator, `RS` (which is a newline by default), to the empty string. An empty `RS` is handled specially to mean that empty lines separate records (instead of newlines).